# open multiple website search queries in background tab from a single form submission

Tags: javascript, html, forms, search, input

How do I open multiple website search queries in background tab from a single form submission on my website?

Sometimes, when I search for a snippet of code, I just launch up three websites and I think it would be cool to just have a single form automate all the other queries.  Just single click a search button and BOOM! 3 background tabs open up with search query.

I would like to merge multiple websites search fields into a single input field submission. Here are the three websites I want to "search":

1. bootsnip
2. bootply
3. codepen

```js
<script>
function dosearch() {
var sf=document.searchform;
var submitto = sf.sengines.options[sf.sengines.selectedIndex].value + escape(sf.searchterms.value);
window.open(submitto);
return false;
}
</script>
```

```html
<form name="searchform" onSubmit="return dosearch();">
Search: 
<select name="sengines">
<option value="https://bootsnipp.com/search?q=" selected>Bootsnip</option>
<option value="https://www.bootply.com/search?kw=modal">Bootply</option>
<option value="https://codepen.io/search/pens?q=modal">codepen</option>
</select>
For: 
<input type="text" name="searchterms">
<input type="submit" name="SearchSubmit" value="Search">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I will use https://cse.google.com/cse in the mean time. Thanks for your attention.